# how to check if Location services is enabled in the device under Google API

Tags: android

I am new all around the Google Api location. and i implemented a class which handaling all the Location call backs.
now its working when the Location services is on. but in case is off i created a function LocationAlertDialog() which should handle this error.
the issue that i dont understand where should i call her in my code because i dont know where i am checking if the GPS or the Network providers are availables.

this is my code:

```
public class LocationTool implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    private Fragment frag;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;
    public OnLocationChangedListener delegate= null;

    public LocationTool (Fragment frag, OnLocationChangedListener onLocationChangedListener)
    {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        delegate = onLocationChangedListener;
        this.frag = frag;
        buildGoogleApiClientAndCreateLocationRequest();
    }

    public boolean ismRequestingLocationUpdates() {
        return mRequestingLocationUpdates;
    }

    public LocationRequest getmLocationRequest() {
        return mLocationRequest;
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getmGoogleApiClient() {
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }

    public Location getmLastLocation() {
        return mLastLocation;
    }

    public void setmLastLocation(Location mLastLocation) {
        this.mLastLocation = mLastLocation;
    }

    public void buildGoogleApiClientAndCreateLocationRequest() {

    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
    }
}

    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(frag.getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        if (mGoogleApiClient!=null)
            Log.d("mGoogleApiClient!=null", "mGoogleApiClient!=null");
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(Constants.DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    public boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(frag.getActivity());
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, frag.getActivity(), Constants.PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(frag.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                frag.getActivity().finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

            // Gets the best and most recent location currently available,
            // which may be null in rare cases when a location is not available.
            Log.d("Connected", "Connected");

            if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
                delegate.startLocationUpdates();
                Log.d("startLocationUpdates", "startLocationUpdates");
            }

            this.setmLastLocation(LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient));
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                Log.d("mLastLocation != null", "mLastLocation != null");
                delegate.updateUI();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(this.frag.getClass().toString(), "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        Log.d("Location services is off","failed");
    }

    public void LocationAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(frag.getActivity());
        alertDialog.setTitle("Location settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("We cannot retrieve your location. Please click on Settings and make sure your Location services is enabled");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        frag.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //tryLocating = false;
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * this function get Longitude and Latitude coordinates and send back the real street address.
     * @param LATITUDE
     * @param LONGITUDE
     * @param ctx
     * @return
     */
    public String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE, Context ctx) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                Log.w("My Current location address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                Log.w("My Current location address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("My Current location address", "Can not get Address!");
        }
        return strAdd;
    }

    /**
     * this function convert real address to geographical coordinates.
     * @param strAddress -real address
     * @return LatLng object which contain the coordinates
     */
    public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {
        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(frag.getActivity());
        List<Address> address;
        LatLng p1 = null;

        try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
            if (address == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();
            p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );
            Log.d("coordinates",p1.latitude+""+p1.longitude);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("Location Exception", "error converting address");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return p1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to check for ON/OFF condition of Location. Use Google Provided `LocationSettingsRequest` which will ask user automatically to enable location when it is OFF. [Sample Project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationSettings) from Google.

Comment: where should i implement it in my code? or if you have any example for that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code check if location is enabled or not. If not enabled it shows alert dialog.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }catch (Exception ex){}
    try{
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }catch (Exception ex){}
    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
        dialog.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {                 
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                Startup.this.startActivity(myIntent);                    
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Dude, you helped me solve a fatal bug that's been affecting my application for a week now. God bless Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code working ? But you are asking about when do you need to check GPS ?? It depends on your goal, what your app is responsible for, if it is GPS tracker, you can check it when first activity starts, or if is not major function in your app, you can just notify but continue working.

I have dealt with the same problem of checking GPS, there are two types of GPS providers available in Android Framework now :

1. Using Google Play Services (it is recommended to use)
2. Using old Location Manager

So I have implemented two strategies for the case when device doesn't have google play services installed.

Base Strategy interface.

```
public interface BaseLocationStrategy {
    void startListeningForLocationChanges(LocationChangesListener locationListener);

    void stopListeningForLocationChanges();

    void setPeriodicalUpdateEnabled(boolean enable);

    void setPeriodicalUpdateTime(long time);

    Location getLastLocation();

    void initLocationClient();

}
```

Location change listener interface

```
public interface LocationChangesListener {
    void onLocationChanged(Location location);
    void onConnected();
    void onConnectionStatusChanged();
    void onFailure(String failureMessage);

}
```

And concrete implementation

```
public class GooglePlayServiceLocationStrategy implements
        BaseLocationStrategy,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    private Context mAppContext;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationChangesListener mLocationListener;
    private boolean mUpdatePeriodically = false;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static GooglePlayServiceLocationStrategy INSTANCE;
    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static long DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters

    private GooglePlayServiceLocationStrategy(Context context) {
        this.mAppContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void startListeningForLocationChanges(LocationChangesListener locationListener) {
        this.mLocationListener = locationListener;
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopListeningForLocationChanges() {
        mLocationListener = null;
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public static BaseLocationStrategy getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new GooglePlayServiceLocationStrategy(context);
            INSTANCE.initLocationClient();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPeriodicalUpdateEnabled(boolean enable) {
        this.mUpdatePeriodically = enable;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPeriodicalUpdateTime(long time) {
        UPDATE_INTERVAL = time < FASTEST_INTERVAL ? FASTEST_INTERVAL : time;
    }

    @Override
    public Location getLastLocation() {
        return this.mLastLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void initLocationClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
        mLocationRequest = createLocationRequest();
    }

    protected synchronized GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mAppContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationListener.onConnected();
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mUpdatePeriodically) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mLocationListener.onConnectionStatusChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        mLocationListener.onFailure(connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

    /**
     * Starting the location updates
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    /**
     * Creating location request object
     */
    protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT); // 10 meters
        return locationRequest;
    }

    /**
     * Stopping location updates
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        mLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
    }


}
```

And finally for old way

```
public class LocationManagerStrategy implements BaseLocationStrategy, LocationListener {
    private Context mAppContext;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private LocationChangesListener mLocationListener;
    private boolean mUpdatePeriodically = false;
    private static LocationManagerStrategy INSTANCE;
    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static long DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters

    private LocationManagerStrategy(Context context) {
        this.mAppContext = context;
    }

    public static LocationManagerStrategy getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new LocationManagerStrategy(context);
            INSTANCE.initLocationClient();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void startListeningForLocationChanges(LocationChangesListener locationListener) {
        mLocationListener = locationListener;
        try {

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    UPDATE_INTERVAL,
                    DISPLACEMENT, this);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopListeningForLocationChanges() {
        try {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setPeriodicalUpdateEnabled(boolean enable) {
        mUpdatePeriodically = enable;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPeriodicalUpdateTime(long time) {
        UPDATE_INTERVAL = time;
    }

    @Override
    public Location getLastLocation() {
        if (mLastLocation == null) {
            try {
                mLastLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(getBestProvider());
            } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return mLastLocation;
    }

    private String getBestProvider() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        return mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void initLocationClient() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        mLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
        if (!mUpdatePeriodically) {
            this.stopListeningForLocationChanges();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        mLocationListener.onConnectionStatusChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        mLocationListener.onConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        mLocationListener.onFailure(provider);
    }
}
```

Comment: again what function i call to check GPRS availability ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google api client's locationservices api to check for gps availability as follows:

```
   public static boolean enableLocationSettings(final Activity activity) {
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        if (!AppConstants.isGPSDialogShown) {
            GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                            try {
                                status.startResolutionForResult(
                                        activity, AppConstants.REQUEST_GPS);
                                AppConstants.isGPSDialogShown = true;
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if someone had to do all this in a fragment.
To enable location services in fragment create `view()` a method

```
isLocationServicesThere()
```

after that declare all this as a function definition

```
      private void isLocationServicesThere() {


        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        boolean network_enabled = false;

        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
            dialog.setPositiveButton(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
                    //get gps
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton(getActivity().getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
}
```